# Inconsistent Swift error in different laptops

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I'm working on a **Flutter project** in a git repository where it is **cloned among me and my colleagues**. The **app runs okay for my colleagues** but gives me the following errors:

`Redundant conformance of 'AppDelegate' to protocol 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'`

in the following code:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  ...
```

and

`Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword`

in the following code:

```swift
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

Now **I know how to fix the problems above**, ie. remove `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` for the first issue and add `override` for the second one. **These fixes, on the other hand, would break the app for my colleagues**. So now every time I want to work on the project I have to do the above fixes but have to **discard those changes when pushing to the repository**. I don't understand why this happened to me and not my colleagues when we are using the same exact repository.

So my question is:
**Are there some settings that I have to configure in XCode so that I can be in sync with my colleagues? Am I missing something?**

FYI, we're using macOS 10.15, XCode 11.3.

Comment: "FYI, we're using macOS 10.15, XCode 11.3." are all of you on the same version? And on the same version of flutter, too? I suspect that at some point `FlutterAppDelegate` was extended to conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, making it redundant to declare them both, but that your colleagues are on an older version of the frameworks where it's not so.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Aah, I see. It did not occur to me that it could be from **Flutter**. So, no, we are **not on the same version of Flutter**. I'm using **1.12.13+hotfix.5** and the others, I think, is still around **1.10**. Now I have to convince the others to update to see if this was the issue.